# Community License in Developer Org

Tags: community, force.com, site.com

[image: License of Sales force]
How do i enable company community in developer org. In my developer org I have those licenses(In picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to

**Setup -> Customize -> Communities -> Settings -> Enable Communities**

Once you enable communities, you need to make sure

1. You have the 'Manage External Users' and 'Edit Self Service Users'
   Permissions
2. The Enable Customer User button is added to the contact
       page layout

Then you should be able to go to a contact record enable a new customer user

[image]

**Then you can choose the appropriate Communities license**

[image]

This was all done in a free Developer org

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/) which will walk you through all the steps of setting up and configuring a Community.